# Symfony2 multi-table join issues

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm a beginner with Symfony.

I have 2 entities: Stock and Sales. Both have their associated database tables.

Stock has the following structure:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| input       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| output      | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| balance     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| unitcost    | double       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Sales has the following structure:

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cost       | double   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date       | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| profitloss | double   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sid        | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am attempting to create a one-to-many relationship between Stock and Sales.

Stock is a list of all items for sale in a store. Sales is the record of actual purchases of any item in the Stock database table.

It was in the process of displaying my first Sales item that I experienced a major problem.

To display a Sale, my vision was to execute an SQL statement between both table where Sales:sid == Stock:id - I ran into newbie problems as I couldn't find a straight forward way of doing the kind of SQL execution I have become accustomed to.

How can I make a start on this? I want to print details of each sale by fetch related data from the Stock table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine handles this sort of thing for you.You can create a Bidirectional one-to-many association as in [One-to-Many Association](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional).
so Your stock Entity will be like

```
class Stock{
 ...

 /**
 *@OneToMany(targetEntity="YourBundleNamespace\Entity\Sale", mappedBy="stock")
 *
 */
 protected $sales;

}
```

---

```
class Sale{  

protected $id;
....
/**
*@ManyToOne(targetEntity="YourBundleNameSpace\Entity\Stock", inversedBy="sales")
*@JoinColumn(name="sid", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $stock;

}
```

---

then simply find your desired Sale Entity Controller and call `$sale->getStock()` and you will get the `Stock` Entity associated with that sale.

For sql Execution doctrine has the ability to execute raw sql but it's better that you use doctrine's dql and `QueryBuilder`. see [dql](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) and [QueryBuilder](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Comment: Thank you. I was having difficulty setting that up correctly.